# Customize controller view of nativescript-exoplayer

Tags: android, nativescript, exoplayer, angular2-nativescript

I am using nativescript-exoplayer as videoplayer in my app with angular.nativescript-exoplayer default controller view does not show fullscreen button.But I need to add one for my app.Is there any way I can customise this default view of player controller.I have checked plugin file but I couldn't find the file that set that default view.I have already built the logic to use the player in fullscreen but couldn't find any way to bind that logic to player controls.
Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's Apple lets you customize AVPlayerViewController. The easier alternative would be placing the player in a Layout and position your custom button somewhere on the layout of your choice, more like an overlay.

Comment: I dont know if im asking something strange but as exoplayer is not an inbuilt player view of its controller must be defined somewhere in plugin files.Could'nt I customize it from there?also im trying to implement this only for android not ios

Comment: View Controller is generally a term used in iOS. Let me have a look what can be done for Android.

Comment: There is a [good blog post](https://geoffledak.com/blog/2017/09/11/how-to-add-a-fullscreen-toggle-button-to-exoplayer-in-android/) about adding full screen button. You will have to do the same (customising `exo_playback_control_view.xml`)  to include the fullscreen button, then add click listeners by overriding [_setupMediaController](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-exoplayer/blob/master/src/videoplayer.android.ts#L311) method form plugin.